# ng-table: Put data-title in a ng-repeat why doesn't work ? Another solution?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I use Jade and coffeescript in my project.

My jade code:

```
table.table(ng-table="videoTableParams", show-filter="true")

    tr(ng-repeat="video in $data")
        td(data-title="'Name'", sortable="'name'", filter="{ 'name': 'text' }")
            a(ui-sref="video.info({ videoId: video.id })") {{ video.name }}
        td(data-title="'Format'", sortable="'format'", filter="{ 'format': 'text' }") {{ video.format }}
        td(data-title="'Duration [s]'", sortable="'duration'") {{ video.duration | number:0 }}
        td(ng-repeat="buttons in controlButtons")
            {{ buttons.title }}
            button#btnRemove.btn.btn-sm.btn-info(ng-show="buttonShow({ videoId: video.id , state:buttons.detail.show , value: 0})", data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="bottom", title="{{ buttons.detail.title }}", ng-click="clickFunction({ videoId: video.id , function: buttons.detail.click })")
                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-wrench
                button#btnRemove.btn.btn-sm.btn-info(ng-show="video.prepare_state == 0", data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="bottom", title="{{ buttons.detail.title }}", ng-click="clickFunction({ videoId: video.id , function: buttons.detail.click })")
            .progress(ng-show="buttonShow({ videoId: video.id , state:buttons.detail.show , value: 2})")
                .progress-bar.progress-bar-striped.active(role='progressbar', aria-valuenow='60', aria-valuemin='0', aria-valuemax='100', style='width: 100%;')
                    .bar(style='width: 20%;')
            button#btnRemove.btn.btn-sm.btn-success(ng-show="buttonShow({ videoId: video.id , state: buttons.detail.show , value: 1 })", data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="bottom", title="{{ buttons.detail.title }}", ng-click="clickFunction({ videoId: video.id , function: buttons.detail.click })")
                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-ok

        td(data-title="")
            button#btnRemove.btn.btn-sm.btn-danger(ng-hide="video.file_exist", data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="bottom", title="Remove this video", ng-click="showRemoveVideoModal(video)")
                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash
```

My coffeescript code :

```
# Prepare table copmonent
    $scope.videoTableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            # show first page
        count: 10,          # count per page
        sorting: {
            name: 'asc'     # initial sorting
        },
        filter: {
            name: ''
        }
    }, {
        total: $scope.videos.length, # length of data
        getData: ($defer, params) ->
            # use build-in angular filter
            orderedData = if params.sorting() then $filter('orderBy')($scope.videos, params.orderBy()) else $scope.videos
            filteredData = if params.filter() then $filter('filter')(orderedData, params.filter()) else orderedData

            $scope.filteredVideos = filteredData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count())
            params.total(filteredData.length)
            $defer.resolve($scope.filteredVideos)
    })
```

I think with data-title it will not work because only one title is for all my buttons title.

if i had data-title in this td

```
td(ng-repeat="buttons in controlButtons" , data-title="buttons.title")
```

buttons is undefined, i have try with a lot of solution as controlButton[$index]['title'] but $index doesn't work so i have do a function to random title and it's work, but only one title for all the collumns, i think data-title doesn't work dynamicaly. I have try to do this with thead but i have not sorting and filter ....

Thanks for the response !

Comment: can you be more specific,what does it mean not work,what error?,is not sorting?you talking about this row `td(ng-repeat="buttons in controlButtons")` ?

Comment: i have edit the post, i hope it's more specific

Comment: there is always problem with dynamic headers in ngtable,did you make header template like here http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/18 and it does not sort and filter ?

Comment: Yes but i'm newbi, thanks for help i go try with the header, i think it's the only issue.

Comment: you may set up plunk/jsfiddle or i can set up plunk lit bit later ,so we can figure out this problem